# Specifying axis's step sizes in graph

Tags: plot, graph, gnuplot, octave, axis

I'm trying to plot a graph in Octave. How can I specify the axis's step size? For example, by default x axis's step size is 0.5(0---0.5---1---1.5---), I want to make it 0.1, and y axis's step size 0.01.

Comment: In gnuplot, you can do `set xtics 0.1`.  I don't know if there is a way in Octave to send commands directly to gnuplot though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will change the step size on the x axis of an existing plot to 0.1:

```
xbounds = xlim()
set(gca, 'xtick', xbounds(1):0.1:xbounds(2))
```

You can do the same thing for the y axis using `ylim` and `'ytick'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can resize the steps of the **x** axis with the below code:

```
set(gca,'XTick',[0:0.1:10]); %[start: step: end]
```

In order to resize the steps of the **y** axis you can do the same:

```
set(gca,'YTick',[0:0.01:10]); %[start: step: end]
```